# is there anyway to get redux state updated data with in same onSubmit method after submitting formik?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik, redux-toolkit

Currently I am using **React**, **Redux Toolkit** and  **Formik**  in my current project and the situation is that while i am submitting form data (using useFormik() hook) with help onSubmit method; with in onSubmit method i am calling Redux action (using useDispatch() hook) then access the state data directly using useSlector hook but i am getting always previous value. The sample codes are given below :

```html
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit : (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values));
      dispatch(loginSumbmit(values));    
      console.log(authState); // get previous data
    },
    validationSchema,
  });
```

Comment: @xadm actually redux is working fine because of when i render the sate object (authState) in <sapn> the updated values are showing but while i am accessing the state object getting previous value with in Formik onSubmit method . is it Formik  problem ?

Comment: no, this is the way redux is working ... you still don't understand HOW it (redux) is working

Comment: sorry i am new in react redux

Answer (score 2):

The majority of the time you do this in regards to Formik is to check for validation errors. Assuming you're using `createAsyncThunk` from Redux-Toolkit for `loginSumbmit`, you can get the payload immediately after and check for errors/success by doing this:

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit : async (values) => {
      const resultAction = await dispatch(loginSumbmit(values));
      if (loginSumbmit.fulfilled.match(resultAction)) {
        // it was a success, you can check resultAction.payload or use `unwrapResult`
      } else {
          // there was an error, handle it
      }

    },
    validationSchema,
  });
```

Another option would be:

```js
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    onSubmit : values => dispatch(loginSumbmit(values))
    .then(unwrapResult)
    .then(originalPromiseResult => {
        // do something with the success payload
    })
    .catch(serializedError => {
        // do something with the error payload
    }),
    validationSchema,
  });
```

There is an example of this exact behavior in the docs here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#examples

In general, you should never need an exact snapshot of the store immediately following a thunk in the same tick. Anything that you're trying to get with a selector should be available in the payload that caused the store to change.